# Retrieve keys inside the brackets in a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have the following string with a SQL command:

```
string sql = "select [x] from table where field = [y] order by [w], [z]";
```

I would like to get the keys inside the `[brackets]` (x, y, w, z, etc...), how could I do this with C#? Is there any way to do it with regex (not necessary)?

I try to do something with `while` statement but it does not work.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, because I'm thinking if you could elaborate more on the actual goal and not this subset of your goal we could give you a more correct way to do what you wish to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
@"\[(.)]"
```

This will capture the letter inside the `[]` when using the `Matches` method of `Regex`.

Since you may have [*words*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034371/retrive-keys-inside-the-brackets-in-a-string/13034421#comment17695048_13034421) inside the brackets, the regex is somewhat more complicated.

I will assume that these will never include an escaped `]` - so the following should work:

```
@"\[([^\]]+)]"
```

Usage:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("select [x] from table where field = [yy] order by [w], [z]", @"\[([^\]]+)]");

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
  foreach(Group group in match.Groups)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(group.Value);
  }
}
```

Note that there is a default group in `match.Groups`, so you will get duplicates.

Comment: Hi Oded, thank you for the awser. Sometimes I have words inside the [brackets] too, It will work with, for sample: `[varname]`, `[date]` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
string sql = "select [x] from table where field = [jkjlh] order by [w], [z]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(sql,@"\[(.*?)\]");
var result = Enumerable.Cast<Match>(matches).Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
```

result will contain the list of strings with the keys.